# Problems with Linq-to-SQL join query

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, join

```
var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();
        grid.DataSource = from booking in bookings
                         join f in getallAttendees on booking.UserID equals f.UserID into fg
                         from fgi in fg.DefaultIfEmpty() //Where(f => f.EventID == booking.EventID)
                          where
                              booking.EventID == id

                          select new
                          {
                              EventID = booking.EventID,
                               UserID = booking.UserID,
                              TrackName = booking.Name,
                              BookingStatus = booking.StatusID,
                               AttendeeName = booking.FirstName,
                             // name = account.FirstName,
                              AmountPaid = booking.Cost,
                              AttendeeAddress = booking.DeliveryAdd1,
                              City = booking.DeliveryCity,
                               Postcode = booking.Postcode,
                              Date = booking.DateAdded,
                              product = fgi == null ? null : fgi.productPurchased
                         };
```

`Booking` table design:

```
ID, EventID, UserID, BookingStatus, AmountPaid, AttendeeAddress, City, Date
```

`Product` table design:

```
ID, EventID, SecondDriver, Apples, Bananas, SecondItem
```

The association between booking and product table is many to many and the foreign key is `UserID`

The above Linq-to-SQL query returns the data of only users whose `booking.UserID equals att.UserID`, what I want is to return all the users of that particular event also with apples and banana fields if they have bought else fill null in that columns.

Any possible solutions or examples will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for an equivalent to a Left Join. You can accomplish this by using the `DefaultIfEmpty()` extension method. Modify your join statement and add another `from in` like so:

```
join at in getallAttendees on booking.UserID equals at.UserID into attg
from att in attg
```

In your select statement you can use the ternary operator `? :` like so:

```
SecondItem = att == null ? null : att.SecondItem,
```

**Edit**

Your `bookings` and `getallAttendees` IQueryable need to come from the same context if you want to join them together.

Otherwise you will need to use `getallAttendees.ToList()` and `bookings.ToList()`

Comment: still getting The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts. error

Comment: ok that works with some minor problems i will try to solve that , if not will bother you again ;), meantime will accept ur answer